# AngularJS ng-change whenever input changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input of type `email`:

```
<input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="email" required>
```

Now I need to execute some code **whenever** the input is changed. Adding an `ng-change="emailInputChanged()"` only executes my method, in case the entered string is a valid e-mail address, but I need the callback to be executed with **every keystroke**, even though the input does not validate. (same issue of course when watching the model à la `$scope.$watch('user.email', emailInputChanged)`.

Any angular way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the onInput event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp
Create a custom directive and listen for the "input" event on your text field element.

Example of the directive implementation:

```
function OnInput() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '',
    scope: {
      whenInputChanged: '&'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.on('input', $scope.whenInputChanged);
    }
  };
}

angular.module('App')
  .directive('onInput', OnInput);
```

To apply the event listener in the template:

```
<input type="email" on-input when-input-changed="change()" name="email" required/>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Woohooo, that looks awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Dmitri, really neat solution. That's the beauty of angular.

Answer (score 2):

since you have given the type as **email** it will call the *ng-change* only when its a valid so remove the type attribute

Comment: That does not help, the function does not even get called when the input does not validate, as stated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-keyup` instead. This would be the same even with basic (native or jQuery) events, as form will react normally only on field blur.

To catch also paste events, use the `ng-paste` directive (see https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/directive/ngPaste)

Comment: It will not work for the case when user pasts the email using mouse click paste

Comment: Pasting seems like an edge case, so this solution seems almost perfect. Still: Any way to cover the described case, @DmitriPavlutin?

Comment: There is a good event "input", which could cover your problem. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp But it should be adapted to Angular.